# Table disappears after AJAX function has run

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby-on-rails, ajax

For some reason after a click my button that requests data from my controller, my table disappears. Here is my table:

```
    <div id="SelectedTm" style= float:right>
    <table id = "PlyrsTm2" style = float:right>
        <tr><th id="PTTitle" colspan=2>List of players on selected team</th></tr>
        <tr><th id="PTHRows">Player</th><th id="PTHRows">Team</th></tr>
        <% @pl.each do |f| %>
            <tr><td class="player"><%= f.Plyr %></td><td class="team"><%= f.Team%></td></tr>
        <% end %>
    </table>
</div>
```

Here is the button that triggers my jquery with ajax

```
<button id="showbtn">Select Team</button>
```

Here is the jquery and ajax:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('#showbtn').on('click', function() {
        ids = $('#teams').val()
        IM = false
    $.ajax({
        url: "http://localhost:3000/teamplayers.json?resolution="+ids+"&import="+IM,
        type:"get",
        dataType: "json",
        cache: true,
        success:function(data){
        $('#PlyrsTm2').html(data);
            alert("Loading Players...."); 
            },
        error: function(error) {
                   alert("Failed " + console.log(error) + " " + error)
                   }           
                   });
    $('#PlyrsTm2').trigger('create');
    return false;
            });

});
```

Now as you can see, my table is populated by rails. Every time i select a new team the table disappears. And only re-appears if I reload the page, but that is the originally selected team, which by default is the first one.

**UPDATE**
Here is my controller:

```
class TeamplayersController < ApplicationController
    before_filter :set_id
    before_action :set_id, :set_teamplayer, only: [:show, :edit, :update, :destroy]

# GET /teamplayers
# GET /teamplayers.json
def index
  @teamplayers = Teamplayer.all
  @fteams = Fteam.all
  tid = params[:resolution]
  toimport = params[:import]

puts tid
  if tid.nil? == true
    tid = 1
        @ids = tid
        @pl =  Teamplayer.joins(:live_player).where(:teamid => @ids).all
  else
    tid = tid.to_i;
        @ids = tid
        @pl =  Teamplayer.joins(:live_player).where(:teamid => @ids).pluck(:Plyr, :Team)
  end
  if toimport == "true"
    @turl = Fteam.where(:id => @ids).pluck(:TeamUrl)

    @turl = @turl[0]  

    system "rake updateTm:updateA[#{@turl},#{@ids}]"
  end


end


# GET /teamplayers/1
# GET /teamplayers/1.json
def show
end

# GET /teamplayers/new
def new
  @teamplayer = Teamplayer.new
end

# GET /teamplayers/1/edit
def edit
end

# POST /teamplayers
# POST /teamplayers.json
def create
  @teamplayer = Teamplayer.new(teamplayer_params)

  respond_to do |format|
    if @teamplayer.save
      format.html { redirect_to @teamplayer, notice: 'Teamplayer was successfully created.' }
      format.json { render action: 'show', status: :created, location: @teamplayer }
    else
      format.html { render action: 'new' }
      format.json { render json: @teamplayer.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
    end
  end
end

# PATCH/PUT /teamplayers/1
# PATCH/PUT /teamplayers/1.json
def update
  respond_to do |format|
    if @teamplayer.update(teamplayer_params)
      format.html { redirect_to @teamplayer, notice: 'Teamplayer was successfully updated.' }
      format.json { head :no_content }
    else
      format.html { render action: 'edit' }
      format.json { render json: @teamplayer.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
    end
  end
end

# DELETE /teamplayers/1
# DELETE /teamplayers/1.json
def destroy
  @teamplayer.destroy
  respond_to do |format|
    format.html { redirect_to teamplayers_url }
    format.json { head :no_content }
  end
end

private
  # Use callbacks to share common setup or constraints between actions.
  def set_teamplayer
    @teamplayer = Teamplayer.find(params[:id])
  end

# Never trust parameters from the scary internet, only allow the white list through.
def teamplayer_params
  params.require(:teamplayer).permit(:playerid, :teamid)
end
end
```

So what is going wrong here, because i notice that it is calling every records individual page but why is it now giving my back the the information from my query as the data instead?

Comment: are you sure that the returned data is not empty?

Comment: no, actually i am not sure how can i check that

Comment: console.log is your friend, try `console.log(data)` in your `success` function

Comment: ok i did, and it says undefined, but why is it now returning anything? I thought by the way i am doing this, it would load the table with the data I need

Comment: can't it just rebuild my rails table

Answer (score 0):

Looks like the statement `ids = $("#teams").val();` will return undefined, since there is no element with id="teams".

If ids is undefined, it's likely that data is null or undefined in this function call:

```
function(data){
    $('#PlyrsTm2').html(data);
    alert("Loading Players...."); 
}
```

If data is null, calling html(null) will cause all your table data to disappear.

So, the solution is to populate `ids` correctly. I'm not sure what `ids` is supposed to do, but that's most likely the solution.

Comment: The teams element is a dropdown selection. and when the button is clicked(#showbtn), then ids is set. See the previous comments I have recently made for my current situation as i have updated my post

Answer (score 0):

```
$('#PlyrsTm2').html(data);
```

That's why your table disappears

The problem is you're  replacing the *content* of this element (not the element itself). To fix this, I'd do this:

```
$('#SelectedTm').html(data);
```

Comment: Changed that and it still disappered, so why will it not redraw the table with the new data?

Comment: What data are you receiving back from the call?

Comment: and active record from a query. and here is what comes back in the data: `Object { playerid="1625", teamid="1", url="http://localhost:3000/teamplayers/527.json"}, Object { playerid="1625", teamid="1", url="http://localhost:3000/teamplayers/528.json"}, Object { playerid="1192", teamid="1", url="http://localhost:3000/teamplayers/529.json"}` What I need is for it to give me data from the index part of my controller. I have posted my controller above